# Is it possible to drastically reduce the number of JS files being served from Magento without merging/bundling?

Tags: magento2, javascript, magento2.3

Currently my almost-new Magento 2.3.1-based website with a lightly modified theme is sending **170** JavaScript files to the browser, **just to serve the home page**. To me, this is not remotely acceptable.

Many of these JS files are useless for my website (e.g. ones relating to Amazon Pay, captcha, etc.) and I would like to remove them completely. Frankly I don't even understand why such files are being sent on the home page, which contains no kind of interactive features (it's just a CMS page).

It seems like Magento is sending lots of unnecessary JavaScript "just in case" it needs to be used for the theme.

Is there a reasonably easy way to identify where this extra bloat comes from, and stop it being sent altogether?

(Please note I don't want to use Magento's JS bundling feature but rather I'm looking for ways to stop these JS files being referenced at all).

Comment: Please share with us if any solution found by you for this because we are also struggling with high volume of JS.

Comment: @VishV Our solution was to abandon Magento and never look back; a solution I highly recommend.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can remove unnecessary Magento modules via composer.json

https://www.integer-net.com/removing-unused-core-modules-from-magento-2-the-right-way/

Comment: Thanks, but even after removing that entire list of modules I'm still seeing the same number of JavaScript files on the frontend. For example, 60 .js files come from the Magento_Ui module. I feel like this is a deeper architectural problem with Magento but I'm open to other solutions.